# Нужна запятая, тире или - запятая и тире? Почему?

Tags: пунктуация

> Она всегда кусала меня за пятки, шавка злая!

В этом предложении нужна запятая, тире или - запятая и тире? Почему?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Грамматика**

При решении задачи прежде всего определяется грамматика предложения как в целом, так и для отдельных слов и словосочетаний. Это простое предложение, в котором есть приложение, выраженное словосочетанием.

Вспомним, что **приложение – это определение**, выраженное существительным и обычно согласованное с ним в падеже. В правилах письма рассматриваются **три вида определений:** согласованные определения, несогласованные определения и приложения. Они имеют свои особенности, но есть и **общие правила**.

Определения всех трех видов могут обособляться или не обособляться в зависимости **от различных факторов.** Мы смотрим, чем выражено приложение и определяемое слово (обычно существительное или местоимение), а также учитываем позицию определения по отношению к определяемому слову.

2. **О позиции приложения**

Определение может находиться до и после определяемого слов или **на расстоянии от него.** И вот последний фактор очень важен, так как он **однозначно** задает необходимость обособления во всех случаях.

Итак, «она» – подлежащее и определяемое слово для распространенного приложения  «шавка злая». Приложение находится в конце предложения, на расстоянии от определяемого слова, поэтому **обязательно обособляется**. Остается выбрать знак.

**Примечание.** В нашем случае определяемое слово выражено личным местоимением, но и для нарицательного существительного все сказанное тоже подойдет.

Кстати, если определяемое слово является  местоимением, то обособление **обязательно** для любой позиции. Но для нарицательных существительных основным фактором является именно дистантная позиция приложения.

3. **Запятая как основной знак**

Основным знаком в этой теме (обособление определений всех видов)  можно считать **запятую**, для использования других знаков потребуется **обоснование.**

*Она всегда кусала меня за пятки, **шавка злая**!*

Теперь присмотримся к самому приложению. Оно имеет явное **оценочное значение**. Из контекста ясно, что речь идет о собаке: автор сообщает нам какую-то основную информацию и попутно выражает свое **субъективное отношение** к ней. У Розенталя есть примеры с такими оценочными приложениями, и там они обособлены запятыми:

*Ты держи его, держи, а то уйдёт, анафема* (Ч.; имеется в виду налим); «Сумасшедшего хоронят». — «*А-а! Тоже отжил, голубчик, своё»* (Фед.); *Так и нужно. В другой раз пусть не фискалит, **каналья*** (Купр.).

4. **Запятая или тире?**

Интересно отметить то, что такие выражения близки **к междометным сочетаниям**, которые также выделяются запятыми: *Тут ещё на грех рана на бедре открылась, **чёрт бы её драл*** (Перв.). Они попутно выражают эмоции говорящего, а не текущую информацию, при этом обычно **тесно сливаются** с основным содержанием речи.

Именно поэтому для обособления здесь желательно выбрать  запятые. Тире – это **сильный выделительный знак**, для его применения в данном случае  нет необходимости. Оценочная информация  выразительнее смотрится именно **при тесной связи** оценочного слова  с передаваемой информацией, а тире потребует паузы, нарушит эту связь. Поэтому вариант с тире можно считать авторским выбором.

6. И уж конечно нет никаких оснований для использования **запятой и тире**.  В данном случае это будет единый знак, а его применение регламентируется специальными  правилами – обычно он используется в сложных распространенных предложениях.

Comment: Насколько я понял, в справочнике не прописано прямо, что приложение может быть на расстоянии от определяемого слова? То есть это следует только из примеров?

Comment: Я тоже поискала эту информацию у Розенталя, но не нашла, чтобы было прописано прямо. Поэтому я и говорю о трех видах определений и общих законах при обособлении.  И вот для несогласованных и согласованных определений эту информацию можно найти. Да оно и по логике понятно.

Comment: Зато я нашёл у Лопатина! "§ 61. Распространенные приложения, стоящие после определяемого слова — существительного или местоимения, **а также отделенные от них другими членами предложения** (выделение моё - N.) или относящиеся к отсутствующему члену предложения, обособляются запятыми: ... *Они очень разные, эти строки, они противостоят друг другу* (Зал.); *Он думал всю эту ночь, Вершинин-старший* (Зал.); *Он был горек и духовит, этот крылатый, степной, восточный ветер* (Шол.)...".

Comment: Прекрасно! У меня была мысль туда зайти, но  не осуществилась...  Поэтому спасибо вам от общества.

Comment: Но здесь не такое приложение, а обзывание, поэтому, в отличие от примеров Лопатина, такая перестановка не подходит: *Она, шавка злая, всегда кусала меня за пятки!* "Шавка злая" можно оформить как новое предложение, в отличие от примеров Лопатина, где приложение поясняет, а здесь не пояснение, а эмоции. Улавливаете разницу? Но можно так: *Она — шавка злая! — всегда кусала меня за пятки.*

Comment: Я разницу улавливаю, но у Розенталя в подобных случаях (при экспрессивной оценке) ставится запятая.

Comment: В какой позиции? Если в середине предложения с запятыми, тогда двусмысленность.

Comment: В конце предложения, конечно, это  стандартное оформление для подобных высказываний. Ваш вариант возможен, но нужно видеть реальное предложение, чтобы сделать выбор. А у нас только условная схема, с такими неинтересно работать. А реальное предложение все мы видели.

Comment: *Она, шавка злая, всегда кусала меня за пятки!* Но здесь не может быть экспрессивной оценки, так только пояснение (кто такая она).

Comment: Нет, этот вариант в качестве оценочного  не подойдет, а пояснение выглядит так: Она шавка злая, всегда кусала меня за пятки!  Для выражения экспрессии шавку надо в конец предложения отправить.  А ваш вариант выглядит неоправданно сложным по использованным средствам. Если только она совсем кого-то загрызла, тогда да. :))

Comment: Так сказуемое, а не пояснение. Речь о том, что в позиции посередине запятые нельзя, если есть определяемое слово.

Comment: А у Розенталя есть такой пример: "Тоже отжил, голубчик, своё", Здесь нет пояснения,   но выражены эмоции (сочувствие).

Comment: Если есть определяемое слово, как написано выше, а здесь его нет, как и двусмысленности.

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция именительного темы или именительного представления (темы) в приведённой  разговорной форме поменяла присущий этой фигуре речи порядок слов. Это делает высказывание ещё более экспрессивным, чем типичное построенние.

Существительное и представляющие именительный темы слова всегда изолируются, так как не являются членом предложения, являясь другим — назывным. Применение тире в данном случае безосновательно.

Comment: Мне кажется, именительный темы тут ни при чём. Это обычное распространённое приложение, уехавшее в конец предложения вследствие разговорного стиля. Сравните: *"Она, шавка злая, всегда кусала меня за пятки!"* Если бы там был именительный темы, предложение при переносе конструкции на привычное место должно было бы выглядеть так: *"Шавка злая — она всегда кусала меня за пятки!"* — что не смотрится уместно.